# Problem with EFI entry after update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

I updated Ubuntu 14.04 (`aptitude update`, `safe-upgrade`).
After that I checked EFI (`efibootmgr -v`) and found that EFI entry for Ubuntu is absent.
I tried create new entry:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi -L ubuntu
```

No new entry and I have error message:

```
efivars: set_variable() failed: status=-28
```

Current version:

```
3.13.0-68-generic #111~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did you use sudo? I have seen this as a command: `sudo efibootmgr -c -l "\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI" -L ubuntu -d /dev/sdX -p N`
where /dev/sdX is the disk and N is the partition number of the ESP, which looks the same as yours, just different order.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I did.  `/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)`

Comment: Looks like (old) bug 1173423.  When you just list the EFI entries with efibootmgr -v, how many do you see?  Could be a nvram space problem.

Comment: @ubfan1, yes I also saw old bug ticket with the same problem. Now I have 13 entries (0000 - 000D). But before this update I had 14 entries (0000 - 000E) and I have `BootCurrent: 000E` now!

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging, and the "-28" error you're getting translates to Linux's `ENOSPC`, which means "no space left on device":

http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-0.99.2/S/32.html

This in turn in translated from EFI's `EFI_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`:

http://wiki.phoenix.com/wiki/index.php/EFI_STATUS#EFI_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

In other words, the firmware is unable to save a new entry. It could be that rebooting once or twice will clear the problem. Another possibility is that you may have too many boot entries. Try doing `efibootmgr -v` to see what already exists. If there are lots of duplicate entries, you could try removing one or more of them with `sudo efibootmgr -b #### -B`, where `####` is the number of the entry you want to remove. Even after deleting entries, you may have to reboot once or twice for the change to do any good.

I realize that I'm telling you a reboot may be required to fix the problem and that such an attempt may cause a failure to boot. You may need to stand ready with a bootable USB flash drive or similar tool. (Many servers enable you to mount a virtual USB drive or CD image remotely via their BMCs. Look into this. You could use the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).) Alternatively, you can copy a known-working boot loader and its configuration and support files to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP (that is, `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` from Ubuntu, assuming the ESP is mounted at `/boot/efi`). I cannot guarantee that either approach will work; you may need to be on hand to troubleshoot problems. As you say the affected machine is a production server, you should be very cautious about this. Perhaps your best course of action is to prepare a backup server to take over for a period then schedule some downtime to fix the problem. At the very least, have multiple backup boot methods ready to go on a moment's notice so that you'll have a chance of recovery if/when the system goes down unexpectedly.

Comment: As I understand this isn't space problem: before last update I had 14 entries (0000-000E) in EFI, now I have only 13 (0000-000D). I deleted some entries (`efibootmgr -b #### -B`) with no result (I can't create new entry).  I have Installation USB with Ubuntu 14.04 and wait maintenance time.

Comment: I already had the same problem after update about year ago, the solution was reboot with installation CD and recreate EFI entry from installation CD. The file system is correct (`/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi` and I had `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` and `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`). As I understand there is no EFI entry in NVRAM and current kernel version can't create new EFI entry in NVRAM.

Comment: Looks like Bug 11930: `After reinstalling grub2-efi, system failed to boot. Culprit is that efibootmgr failed to write EFI variables so entries can be deleted but not added and sometimes updated`.

Comment: The error message indicates that it *is* a space issue, or at least a firmware issue. Note that the NVRAM storage is managed by the EFI and includes things other than the boot entries. Thus, the number of entries can go down but storage used might go up. Rebooting often triggers "garbage collection" that can free up space, but I know of no way to be certain that this will help. Deleting an entry without rebooting might or might not free up actual storage space, since garbage collection might be required after deleting entries before the space becomes available.

Comment: Note also that the "device" in the case of the error you're seeing is not your disk -- it's the NVRAM. The problem is not with the files on the disk (although the workaround of using the fallback filename does involve modifying disk files). The problem is with the EFI storage. I think you mis-reported the bug number; Launchpad bug #11930 is about Freetype and has nothing to do with EFI-mode booting.

Comment: you are right, this is not Bug 11930, I only say this bug look like Bug 11930 (I can delete EFI entry but I can't create new entry). May be you are right about "garbage collection". Now I try resolve the problem without reboot and wait maintenance time.